# How to replace a string with another in unix input file is given via command line argument

Tags: bash, unix

1. Unix : Replace Word

Write the unix command to replace the word "Unix" with "Unix OS" in a given file. The file will be given as a command line argument when the script containing your command will run.

Note: The search for "Unix" to replace with "Unix OS" should be case insensitive.

For example,

If the input file contains the following lines

Unix is an multi-user, multi-tasking system It is a command based operating system. We will learn unix in this module.

The output should be

Unix OS is an multi-user multi-tasking

system.

It is a command based operating system. We will learn Unix OS in this module.

Answer (score 2):

It passes all the test cases for case sensitive and insensitive words.

```
sed -e 's/\<Unix\>/Unix OS/I'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is your friend. `"$1"` will be the first argument to your script containing the filename within the script. You want a CAse inSenSITIVE substitution of, e.g. `"uNix"` with `"Unix OS"`, so you will use the normal substitution form `s/find/replace/` and add the `i` option for case-insensitive match and add `g` for global (all) replacement if more than one `"Unix"` in the same line. You will only want to match `"Unix"` and not `"Unixes"` for replacement, so you want to make sure `"Unix"` is at a word-boundary at each end. With `-E` extended regex, you can use `\b` to mark a word boundary.

In your script you could do:

```
sed -E 's/\bUnix\b/Unix OS/ig' "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "uNix and Unix and unixes\n" | sed -E 's/\bunix\b/Unix OS/ig'
Unix OS and Unix OS and unixes
```